# Very Slow Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

My old computer, running a 32-bit version of Windows XP, was recently upgraded (using a disk) to a 64-bit version of Windows 7 and its very slow!

Before, when it's still running Windows XP 32-bit, it was somewhat fast.  Firefox often responds a lot, and seldom "not responding"s.  I can open Firefox and MS PowerPoint (2007) at the same time, but with almost no lags (but I think, that's okay! ...).

But now, when it was upgraded to Windows 7 64-bit, it was very slow.  Firefox often lags a lot, and often "not responding".  When I open Firefox and MS PowerPoint (2010) at the same time, it frequently lags, and both of them does not respond.

On Windows XP, the highest Physical Memory I can see, is maybe 80%.  On Win 7, the highest Physical Memory I can see, is 97 - 98%; which means, it will often lag.

Here's my computer specifications:

- Operating System :  Windows 7 64-bit
- Processor :  AMD
- RAM : less than 1.00 GB (around 995.0 MB)

Can a 1.00 GB RAM cannot run a 64-bit system?

---

#### UPDATE:

Since a 1.00 GB RAM cannot run a 64-bit system, I searched and had found a way on how to speed up Windows 7 by making a part of a storage (HDD / SSD) to be a RAM (Virtual Memory).
Well, it does not increase the RAM, but it somewhat boosted the performance of my computer.  It became fast, just a little bit.

Is this stable, or will it make my computer gain speed further?

Comment: Plain and simple: 1GB of RAM is not adequate for running Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Your system doesn't meet the requirements for a 64-bit installation of windows 7 or any 64-bit version of Windows for that matter

Comment: [Windows 7 system requirements on support.microsoft.com](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10737/windows-7-system-requirements) states at least 2 GB of RAM for a 64-bit version and 1 GB for a 32-bit version.

Comment: Well, if that's the problem, the programs (Firefox and MS PowerPoint) are running on 32-bit mode.  But, they still use most of the RAM available.

Comment: What is important is your CPU, if your CPU is 32bits,
(you can find out : Start  > Control Panel > System)
You most likely run a 32bit version of windows and not 64bits as stated.

Otherwise going on some research some people are using emulators, but mostly for compatibility with the O.S, but for an O.S what's the point?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is insufficient memory. Early versions of windows XP ran fine on 64MiB or 128MiB (that is, the OS with allmost no applications open). UP to date versions of XP with a modern browser really want 512MiB or more. And a modern firefox easily consumers a few hundred MiB. So 1GiB (1024MiB) worked.

Bow you moved to windows 7. Windows 7 assumed more memory and it even specified at least 1GiB for win7 32bit and win 7 64 bit. This does not mean that you cannot use win 7 x64 with less memory, but if you do it is likely to behave badly. Or it might just run the OS and have almost no reserves for applications.

This is made slightly worse if you install the 64 bit version of an OS. Binaries (programs) for 64 bit aplications tend to be larger and consume more memory. This is usually not a bad thing since any modern system will ship with 8GiB or more. But if you try to use a modern 64 bit OS on an ancient computer then you run into problems.

In your case the OS and applications use up most of the available memory. Adding a large page file can help a bit because it allows windows to page out unused parts, thus leaving more available for your firefox and ppt applications. But this is merely a workaround. The real solution is to add more memory (assuming the old system supports it and that it is affordable), or to run the applications elsewhere and just use the local desktop as a terminal.  (E.g. see Citrix, windows server etc etc). The latter does imply having a more modern computer elsewhere, which might not be the case at home.

Comment: What do you mean "Page File" ?  Is it the Virtual Memory that I'm talking about?  Should I add more of it to my system to speed it up?

Comment: Virtual memory on windows pages to a pagefile. On the past we had swapping (swp out a whole process). these days any modern OS uses paging (page out parts of a process, not nessecary the whole thing). And both paging and swapping can be backed by a file or a partition. A partition is usually faster, but windows has moved to paging to a file because it is easier to grow a pagefile on a filesystem when needed. If you do not care about the details then you may consider "paging, swapping and virtual memory the same".

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you have a hardware problem.

When using such an old machine you have to limit yourself to using just one programme at the time (either firefox or ms office).

If you still want to continue using that old computer (and windows 7) switching to LibreOffice would be good because it requires less RAM than MS office. It can open all ms office files, save ms office files, and make files smaller on a hard drive.

Btw. I use an old laptop with 1 GB RAM (of which 128 MB is for the graphic card) and I have Lubuntu Linux on it - and multitasking works just fine (Firefox+LibreOffice+Picture editor).

Hope any of this helps, bye